# Capture Nodejs Server Events generated by Request and Response Objects

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, response

I am working on logs of the application just to give you information there are two kind of strategies used inside the application.

1. **POST Process**
2. **PRE Process**

In the first strategy if application has to make some call to third-party applications, it will first send the response to client and after execute that call, so
as my application is using express as framework, I can catch those responses in middle-wares but not in this specific case application is not sending back 
any response as application has already responded to the client.

The second strategy is simple process and at the end send back response this call will be caught by express middle-ware without any issue, so that is the 
model that i am using until now now what I want to do is to catch requests received, and sent by application by standing outside the application, as i
got the idea and understand the structure this is kind of a proxy server which will catch requests not just received by the application but sent by as well, and i know we can catch requests coming in but I am working on the data at runtime
so i don't want those logs i want logs that are coming into the logger application at runtime.

Now coming to the question according to my requirements is there a way to catch requests received, and sent by NodeJS server?

Answer (score 1):

can you try morgan node module for that

Create a new morgan logger middleware function using the given format and options. The format argument may be a string of a predefined name (see below for the names), a string of a format string, or a function that will produce a log entry.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan

Comment: OK I read a little bit about morgan my question is if me application send request out to a third-party application will it be able to log. Is there a strategy for that?

Comment: you can use simple util.log() in that case

Comment: OK let me work on that first after testing that i will post the result here.

Comment: sure,and let me know